# How can Eye of Gnome zoom in and navigate in large images so fast?

Tags: performance, wxpython, pyopengl

Recently, I have been trying to view a large image (size is ~7000x5000 pixels) with PyOpenGL and wxPython. My approach was to load the image and apply it as a texture to a quad which in theory should exploit any graphics acceleration capabilities of my GPU. I use the wxGLCanvas class for OpenGL drawing and event handling.

Then, I compared its performance with Eye of Gnome and found that while my program was painfully slow at zooming in and out of the image, Eye of Gnome had no speed problems: zooming and moving around in the image at some magnification is done almost instantly while my program still has noticeable lag, even after migrating it to Cython.

So, my question is: How does Eye of Gnome (or any other image viewer program) achieve its performance (apart from being written in C)?

edit: I did some tweaking in Cython and now zoom speed is acceptable, but my question still remains the same. I am sure that my program is still slower than Eye of Gnome.